# Write Directly to Video Buffer in Modern OS

Tags: c++, operating-system, hardware, video-card

I want to draw a red line on my monitor directly writing to memory from my C++ code.

I know that modern operating system protect physical memory and it is hard to do.

Assuming that I know video card that I`m currently using (it is nVidia GeForce 820m in my case) also I could give all needed system rights for my application. I know that this is "bad idea". It is just my curiosity.

Is it possible on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Earlier before video accelerator cards came, graphic programmer directly write to video buffer which is located at A000h

Comment: @seccpur: That worked until VGA broke through the 128KB reserved space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. Cross-site duplicate, but you do this by writing to [/dev/fb0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192206) in Linux. Windows doesn't expose the screen like that. And it's most likely not *the* real frame buffer, if that even exists.